# how to get registered users number between defined dates (from | before)?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to get sum of registered users in defined dates which I define?
I'm using MEAN stack. I want something like that: [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date_max_min) and result must be number of registered users in this period. how to make this with mongoose?

something like that:
[image]

this is my html:

```
    <h4>Num of registered users: <strong>{{ regRangeNum }}</strong></h4>
    <span>from: <input type="date"></span>
    <br>
    <span>to: <input type="date"></span>
    <br><br>
    <button class="default">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

```
var getUserCount = function(fromDate,toDate) {
    db.User.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                created_at: {
                    $gte: ISODate(fromDate),
                    $lt: ISODate(toDate)
                }
            }
        },
        { $unwind: "$users" },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                count: {$sum: 1}
            }
        }], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to now how many users was connected between two dates, why don't you use `.count()`?

```
db.User.count({date:{$gte:ISODate("...")}});
```